# Wordpress custom post permalink structure inside custom post permalink

Tags: wordpress

I have custom post structure like this:

mysite.com/custompostname/customposttitle

and i need to have one more custom post type that have depedency with myfirst custom post type so my permalink would be:

mysite.com/custompostname/customposttitle1/custompostname2/custompost2title1
mysite.com/custompostname/customposttitle1/custompostname2/custompost2title2

mysite.com/custompostname/customposttitle2/custompostname2/custompost2title3
mysite.com/custompostname/customposttitle2/custompostname2/custompost2title4

etc..

I to have news section for my custom posts in permalink, for example:

mysite.com/companies/company1/news/news1

Is there way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customise the permalink for a custom post type, but it needs to be hardcoded in the `rewrite` parameter given to `register_post_type`. You could use categories to achieve the same thing though: set up a taxonomy for the first custom post type and then use the posts to create a custom taxonomy for the second CPT (i.e. the posts from the first CPT would become the categories for the second).

So you would add something like this pseudo-code to the edit page for the second CPT:

1. get all posts of type 'CPT1'
2. loop through them to create a list of checkboxes
3. display in a metabox
4. save the result

There are still hoops to be jumped through to get those URLs going to the right place, but it's a start.